# Regexp in C - match group

Tags: c, regex, unix, posix, grouping

I've been struggling with regular expressions in C (just `/usr/include/regex.h`).

---

I have (let's say) hundreds of regexps and one of them can match input string.
Currently I'm doing it (generating it actually) like this: hundreds of do-while with match inside, break if not matching and going to another. One by one:

```
do {
    if ( regex_match(str, my_regex1) != MY_REGEX_SUCCESS ) DO_FAIL; //break
    ...
    if ( sscanf(str, " %d.%d.%d.%d / %d ", &___ip1, &___ip2, &___ip3, &___ip4, &___pref) != 5 ) DO_FAIL; //break
    ...
} while (0);

do {
    if ( regex_match(str, my_regex2) != MY_REGEX_SUCCESS ) DO_FAIL; //break
    ...
    ...
} while (0);

do {
    if ( regex_match(str, my_regex3) != MY_REGEX_SUCCESS ) DO_FAIL; //break
    ...
    ...
} while (0);
```

---

What I'd like to have is something like:

```
const char * match1 = "^([[:space:]]*)([$]([._a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,118})?[._a-zA-Z0-9])([[:space:]]*)$";
const char * match2 = "^([[:space:]]*)(target|origin)([[:space:]]*):([[:space:]]*)([$]([._a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,118})?[._a-zA-Z0-9])([[:space:]]*):([[:space:]]*)\\*([[:space:]]*)$";
const char * match3 = "^([[:space:]]*)(target|origin)([[:space:]]*):([[:space:]]*)([$]([._a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,118})?[._a-zA-Z0-9])([[:space:]]*)/([[:space:]]*)(([0-2]?[0-9])|(3[0-2]))([[:space:]]*):([[:space:]]*)(([1-9][0-9]{0,3})|([1-5][0-9]{4})|(6[0-4][0-9]{3})|(65[0-4][0-9]{2})|(655[0-2][0-9])|(6553[0-5]))([[:space:]]*)$";
char * my_match;
asprintf(&my_match, "(%s)|(%s)|(%s)", match1, match2, match3);


int num_gr = give_me_number_of_regex_group(str, my_match)
switch (num_gr) {
    ...
}
```

and don't have an idea how to do that...

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: I think there is a flaw in the design thought. Why can't you have input string in a file, single column. Have the program read them one after the other and compare one by one with the string?

Comment: Also if you are just comparing strings, why not use the standard C library, specifically: strcmp ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume your `regex_match` is some combination of [`regcomp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/regcomp.html) and `regexec`. To enable grouping, you need to call `regcomp` with the `REG_EXTENDED` flag, but without the `REG_NOSUB` flag (in the third argument).

```
regex_t compiled;
regcomp(&compiled, "(match1)|(match2)|(match3)", REG_EXTENDED);
```

Then allocate space for the groups. The number of groups is stored in `compiled.re_nsub`. Pass this number to `regexec`:

```
size_t ngroups = compiled.re_nsub + 1;
regmatch_t *groups = malloc(ngroups * sizeof(regmatch_t));
regexec(&compiled, str, ngroups, groups, 0);
```

Now, the first invalid group is the one with a -1 value in both its `rm_so` and `rm_eo` fields:

```
size_t nmatched;
for (nmatched = 0; nmatched < ngroups; nmatched++)
    if (groups[nmatched].rm_so == (size_t)(-1))
        break;
```

`nmatched` is the number of parenthesized subexpressions (groups) matched. Add your own error checking.

Comment: Hello, larsmans, Your assumption was correct and this is EXACTLY what I needed, thanks for suggestion. <QUESTION> Will it work even if sub-matches contains grouping itself? I've edited bottom example to ilustrate my question.</QUESTION> Thanks again.

Comment: @DinGODzilla: I can't find any remark on this in the Unix RE standard, so my guess is recursive grouping is implicitly allowed (since not allowing it would complicate specification and implementation). Please try for yourself whether recursive grouping works.

Comment: Thanks for searching... Where I can find posix RE standard? ... To find out if "(?:" or other non-capturing groupings are allowed...

Comment: I am been looking for so long for this answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could have them give you a array of strings that contain your regexps and test each one of them.

```
//count is the number of regexps provided
int give_me_number_of_regex_group(const char *needle,const char** regexps, int count ){
  for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i){
    if(regex_match(needle, regexp[i])){
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1; //didn't match any
}
```

or am i overseeing something?

Answer (score 0):

"I have (let's say) hundreds of regexps ..."

It looks like you are trying to comparing the quad parts of ip addresses. In general, in using regular expressions, its usually a red flag when using that many regex's on a single target and stopping after a match.

example: Which group will correctly match first?
`target ~'American'  ,  pattern ~ /(Ame)|(Ameri)|(American)/`
This does not even include quantifiers in the subgroups.

If its the case of a constant form the regex's are composed of/from, for instance data, it might be better to use C's string functions to split out the data from the form into an array, then compare the array items with the target. C is much faster for this than regex's.