# C++ Subpattern Matching

Tags: c++, c, regex

can anyone please show me an example about using regex (regex.h) in C/C++ to search and/or extracting subpattern in a regex.

in javascript, it will be something like this,

```
var str = "the string contains 123 dots and 344 chars";
var r = /the string contains ([0-9].*?) dots and ([0-9].*?) chars/;
var res = r.exec(str);
var dots = res[1];
var chars = res[2];
alert('dots ' + dots + ' and chars ' + chars);
```

how can i do this using regex.h in c/c++ (not boost or any other libraries) ??

thanks,

Comment: what do you men by 'regex.h not boost or any other'?

Comment: Have you tried googling "c++ regexp example"?

Comment: i'm currently using examples from http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/117525-regex-h-extracting-matches.html

Comment: I think your regex is strange. I'd write `([0-9]+)` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `regex.h` in standard C or standard C++, so I'm assuming you mean the [POSIX regular expression library](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/regex.h.html). C example:

```
char const *str = "the string contains 123 dots and 344 chars";
char const *re_str = "the string contains ([0-9].*?) dots and ([0-9].*?) chars";
regex_t compiled;
regmatch_t *groups;

regcomp(&compiled, re_str, REG_EXTENDED);

ngroups = compiled.re_nsub + 1;
groups = malloc(ngroups * sizeof(regmatch_t));
regexec(&compiled, str, ngroups, groups, 0);

for (size_t i = 0; i < ngroups; i++) {
    if (groups[i].rm_so == (size_t)(-1))
        break;
    else {
        size_t len = groups[i].rm_eo - groups[i].rm_so;
        char buf[len + 1];
        memcpy(buf, str + groups[i].rm_so, len);
        buf[len] = '\0';
        puts(buf);
    }
}
free(groups);
```

(Add your own error checking. For more details, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604522/regexp-in-c-match-group/4604945#4604945).)

Comment: +1 Don't you need to `malloc` 1 more than the number of parenthesized subexpressions (and adjust the regexec call and loop) to account for the whole expression? ie `groups[0]` will indicate the whole string; `groups[1]` will indicate the 1st match ("123") and `groups[2]` (not malloc'd and not regexec'd) will indicate the 2nd match.

Answer (score 1):

The only regular expressions readily available in C++ is `boost::regex`, and that is what has been adopted for the next standard.  And the syntax is:

```
boost::regex expr( "the string contains (\\d*) dots and (\\d*) chars" );
boost::smatch match;
if ( regex_match( text, match, expr ) ) {
    //  We have a match,
    std::string dots = match[1];
    std::string chars = match[2];
    //  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither C nor C++ has a "regex.h". The newest version of C++ (commonly called C++0x) will have regular expression support, but it will be Boost.Regex, more or less. So you may as well just ask, "How do I use Boost.Regex?"

Comment: well, i'm currently using regex.h, according to http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/117525-regex-h-extracting-matches.html, it worked, but i still finding a way to extract sub pattern matches.

Comment: @user777305: So this library you're using comes from the [GNU C library](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Regular-Expressions.html), I take it? Or is it some other library? Simply citing "regex.h" is not sufficient information for us to know what you're talking about.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: `regex.h` is standardized by POSIX.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, sorry, but that's all know.